# Is the sequence $\sqrt{1+\frac{1}{n^2}}$ increasing or decreasing?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

Is the sequence $\sqrt{1+\frac{1}{n^2}}$ increasing or decreasing?

I simplified it to $\frac{\sqrt{n^2+1}}{n}$, and I tried $a_{n+1}-a_n$ and $\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}$, but neither seem to work, how should I proceed?

Comment: What happens for $n = 1$? $n \to \infty$?

Comment: What values can n take

Answer (score 3):

Note that
$$\begin{align}
m>n\quad&\Longrightarrow\quad\frac{1}{m}<\frac{1}{n}\\\\
&\Longrightarrow\quad\left(\frac{1}{m}\right)^2<\left(\frac{1}{n}\right)^2\\\\
&\Longrightarrow\quad\frac{1}{m^2}<\frac{1}{n^2}\\\\
&\Longrightarrow\quad1+\frac{1}{m^2}<1+\frac{1}{n^2}\\\\
&\Longrightarrow\quad\sqrt{1+\frac{1}{m^2}}<\sqrt{1+\frac{1}{n^2}}\\\\
&\Longrightarrow\quad a_m<a_n
\end{align}$$
and thus the sequence is decreasing.

Answer (score 2):

The function $\sqrt(x)$ is monotone, what can you say about the sequence:
$1+1/n^2$?

Answer (score 2):

$\sqrt{1+\frac{1}{n^2}} >  \sqrt{1+\frac{1}{(n+1)^2}}$

$\iff 1+\frac{1}{n^2} >  1+\frac{1}{(n+1)^2}$

$\iff \frac{1}{n^2} >  \frac{1}{(n+1)^2}$

$\iff {n^2} <  {(n+1)^2}$

$\iff {n^2} <  n^2+2n+1$

$\iff 0<  2n+1$

Comment: You started with the fact you wanted to prove and wrote an implication arrow ($\implies$). This isn't logically sound...

Comment: @NajibIdrissi removed that

Comment: An now you wrote $x > y \iff x^2 > y^2$, which isn't true in general (it is if $x$ and $y$ are positive, but you need to be precise about that...).

Comment: @NajibIdrissi It is true in this case... $n \in \mathbb{N}$ is a premise and there are no negative signs..

Comment: You still need to explicitly say it :)

Comment: @NajibIdrissi actually not since this is a sequence. It's not without context.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: you needn't even simplify, you can draw conclusions easily through directly differentiating the function 
$$f(x)=\sqrt{1+\frac1{x^2}},\quad x\ne 0$$
In the case of positive $n$, you need only discuss the sign of $f'(x)$ when $x>0$.

Comment: seems like a painful way to solve the problem...

Comment: @MichaelChirico I think it is rather simple. Calculating the derivative isn't hard: one needs to apply the chain rule only once.